# Find scalar product of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Consider $ u, v\in\mathbb R^{ 3}$ and the following conditions :
 $||u − 3v|| = 5$, $||u|| = || − 2v|| = 2$, then prove $(u,v) = −2$

So this is what i did: Sorry if i made a mistake i am new with scalar product.

From $$||u - 3v||=5$$ i know : 
$$(u,u) + (u,-3v) + (-3v,u) + (-3v,-3v) = 5$$
But this is equal to: 
$$||u||^{ 2} - 6(u,v) - 9||v||^{ 2}= 5$$
From the conditions i know $||u||=||-2v||= |-2|||v||=2$, thus $||v||=1$

Now i know:

$$2^{ 2} - 6(u,v) - 9(1)^{ 2} = 5$$ thus:

$$(u,v)=\frac{-10}{ 6}$$

But this is not the result i wanted to prove. Any hint on what am i doing wrong?

Comment: ok,  even if it is $9||v||^{ 2}$ the result would be $(u,v)=\frac{8}{ 6}$ which is still wrong.

Comment: $$(u,u) + (u,-3v) + (-3v,u) + (-3v,-3v) = 5$$ should be $$(u,u) + (u,-3v) + (-3v,u) + (-3v,-3v) = \color{red}{25}$$

Comment: It is indeed. Could you explain why is it 25?

Comment: Use $\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{a} = \|\mathbf{a}\|^{\color{red}{2}}$

Answer (score 1):

$$(u,u)-6(u,v)+9(v,v)=25$$ or
$$4-6(u,v)+9=25,$$ which gives
$$(u,v)=-2.$$